NTFS large binary file recovery
I just happened to unwillingly delete an important, large, encrypted binary file on my NTFS device by calling C++ write functions with the w flag. All I have done so far is unmounting the device. The file has no structure, such as headers, footers, or magic bytes whatsoever. It's just nearly 116 GB of raw binary data. The file is listed in device directory as an empty file with 0 byte size.
Is there anything I can do besides crying?

UPDATE: The filesystem is on HDD, and the HDD is not encrypted. Here is what I tried:

I unmounted the device that contained the file (/dev/sda3).
I used TestDisk to scan the device.
I found an inode with a size matching my missing file (inode_381265 -> inode_382104 125245022698).
I copied the file (inode_381265) to another device.

However, the file seems to be altered since it's not getting decrypted.
PS: The missing file is an encrypted version of a large 7z file using a custom algorithm. The encryption process is not a standard procedure, but rather a (possibly unsafe) handmade combination of XORing with a key and shifting. There is no metadata embedded in the encrypted data, just raw binary.
Appendix: Screenshot for TestDisk result:


Is the filesystem on SSD or HDD?

@ChrisDavies It's HDD, I managed to recover the file using TestDisk, I'll post the answer.

@ChrisDavies I'd appreciate if you could explain the difference between recovering from SSD and HDD, btw the recovered file seems to be altered...

R-Studio Undelete https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000

@ArtemS.Tashkinov It couldn't find the file in demo (shows file-size as 0), btw its license isn't available in my region.

You might be able to find the 7z header (by decrypting every freespace randomdata block using your method). Then you got the first fragment of your 7z file recovered. Problem will be finding the following fragments. By default 7z itself can't precisely pinpoint corruption, it only has a CRC for each file. So its not very finegrained unless you got very small files in there... so finding the next fragment will be a needle haystack problem. That's all assuming the raw data is still intact and not overwritten into anyway.

...and then 7z does not take kindly to truncated files anyway... so most likely infeasible to recover unless you can coerce ntfs to spit it back out.

@frostschutz, could you explain a bit more about freespace random data block? I was missing a 116.6 GB file, and the inode size seemed ok (125245022698 ÷ (1024^3) = 116.64). I recovered a 116 GB raw data file. My messy encryption method is some kind of a semi-Feistel block cipher, meaning the output cipher for every block is used as input for the next block. I put the whole algorithm here: https://gist.github.com/TadavomnisT/9d1074628eb442a12b3aad10d755e8d9. Given this, ./a.out -dec inode_381265 {KEY} | head -n 1 | hexdump -C should output a valid 7z signature, but it doesn't.

"I'd appreciate if you could explain the difference between recovering from SSD and HDD" - if it's an SSD the likelihood of recovery after truncating a file is pretty much close to zero. With an HDD you do have a chance as the data is still accessible

One strategy that's at least an improvement upon crying is to implement a backup strategy, so you're less likely to face this debacle in the future. And even with a backup regimen in place, when developing code, test your code on a test copy of the data, rather than on the live data directly.
